# Can't calculate growth rate of function with log and fraction

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

I am trying to solve a question about getting growth rate in the image below, but I can't.

[image: formula]

From what I have learned before, if there is a fraction, we usually do not care of denominator, but consider numerator part, which is "2+3n".

Thus, from my perspective the answer is that "2+3n < 2n+3n = 5n with witness c=5 and k=1" or "2+3n < n+3n = 4n with witness c=4 and k=2", both resulting in O(n).

However, this is incorrect according to the answer.

Can you show the whole calculation steps that how I can reach to that answer, Big-theta(root(n)/log(n))?

Comment: Very approximately: (1+4 log n) grows like log n. So you write log n. 2+3n grows like 3n. Finally you get 3/5 * SQRT(n)/log n, which grows like SQRT(n)/log n. You **do** care about denominators -- n/SQRT(n) is SQRT(n), not n.

Comment: @LSerni so you mean like, "(2+3n) / (5SQRT(n) + 20SQRT(n)log n)" -> "2+3n / 20SQRT(n)log n" because "20SQRT(n)log n" dominates "5SQRT(n)" -> "n/SQRT(n)logn" if we don't care constants -> "(n/SQRT(n)) * (1/logn)" -> "SQRT(n) * 1/logn)" becuase (n/SQRT(n)) is SQRT(n) -> "SQRT(n)/log(n)", is this correct?

Comment: Looks like it. Not sure where that factor 20 comes from, though...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to follow [big O notation definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition). For these, I like using the limit definition of big O:

```
f(n) is in O(g(n)) if and only if:
lim n-> infinity |f(n) / g(n)| < infinity
```

Then apply it to your problem where:

```
f(n) = (2+3n)/(5sqrt(n)(1+4logn))
g(n) = sqrt(n) / log(n)
```

And just do some algebra on the result:

```
lim n-> infinity: |f(n)/g(n)| = 
= |(2+3n)log(n)/(5sqrt(n)(1+4logn)sqrt(n))| <= 
<= |5nlog(n)/5sqrt(n)(1+4logn)sqrt(n))| = 
= |nlogn/ (sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) * (1+4logn)| = 
= |nlogn / n(1+4logn)| = 
= |logn / (1+4logn)| <= |logn / 4logn| = 1/4 < infinity
```

From this, and from definition of big O notation, this proves `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))`. You can similarly show big Omega, by showing `lim n->infinity |g(n)/f(n)| < infinity`, and by showing it is both `O(g(n))` and `Omega(g(n))`, you can conclude this is tight bound (`Theta(g(n)`).